# Can I use an array of strings as keys in a recordset?

Tags: arrays, ms-access, vba

I have this small VBA script in an Access database. There are a number of field comparisons I would like to do. In other languages, I would be able to make an array of keys and then use a for..each loop in order to test each key. Something like this:

```
string[] myKeys = { "key1", "key2", "key3" };
foreach(string myKey in myKeys)
{
    if(myRecordset!myKey == myTable!myKey) DoSomething()
}
```

I tried this in VBA, but it gives me Run-time error '3265': Item not found in this collection when using the following code:

```
For Each myKey In myKeys
    If Not IsNull(myR![myKey]) Then Me.Recordset![myKey] = myR![myKey]
Next myKey
```

Is what I am trying to do even possible in VBA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to reference the value of a field whose name is stored in your variable `myKey`, use this ...

```
myR.Fields(myKey)
```

That will work whether your recordset is a DAO or ADO object.

Error 3265, "Item not found in this collection", isn't a complaint about the array.  It's telling you your recordset has no field whose literal name is "myKey".  Perhaps this code will make it clearer.  It works without error as written.  Un-commenting either of the first 2 `Debug.Print` lines will trigger error 3265.

```
Public Sub foo()
    Const myKey As String = "id"
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strSelect As String
    strSelect = "SELECT id FROM MyTable;"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSelect)
    'Debug.Print rs![myKey]
    'Debug.Print rs!myKey
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(myKey)
    rs.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: This works exactly as I want it to. Thanks. There doesn't seem to be much information on Fields unless you explicitly know what it is. This is really my first time doing any type of programming in VBA and it is really a lot different than other languages.

Comment: VBA takes some getting use to.  :-)  If `myR` is a `DAO.Recorset`, in your code you can type `myR.`, then let Intellisense show you the available methods and properties.  You can do the same if it's an `ADODB.Recordset` and if you have set a reference for Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're trying to do here. Is "key1" a fieldname or a value?
When you write myR![myKey], myKey is a fieldname.

If it's supposed to be a value, then you'll get the error. For example, if "key1", "key2", "key3" are employee ID numbers (say 10, 20, & 30), then what you tried to do was ask IsNull(myR![10]), and since there's no field called 10, it gives an error.

Hope this helps.